# Laravel Eloquent doesn't display date/time as in database timezone

Tags: php, json, laravel, eloquent, php-carbon

I'm trying to get the same timezone as my data in MySQL, but the JSON response was replying with a different time.
I tried using Carbon but the results always show the same (different timezone from mine).
Also, I have the timezone in `app.php` to `'timezone' => 'Asia/Kuala_Lumpur'`, to store the data as my country timezone.

```php
$todayentry = SensorTissue::whereDate('entryDate', Carbon::now()->setTimezone(config('app.timezone')))->get()->sortBy('entryDate');
$todayentry = json_decode($todayentry);
return $todayentry;
```

the results from json response:

```
[{
"tsID": 10,
"entryDate": "2020-04-04T23:57:17.000000Z",
"sensorValue": 7
},
{
"tsID": 11,
"entryDate": "2020-04-04T23:57:34.000000Z",
"sensorValue": 6
}]
```

the response shows `2020-04-04T23:57:34.000000Z`
it should be as `2020-04-05 07:57:34` in my database.

Comment: I have same issues recently. I think laravel converts,```created_at``` colum to your config timezone. Meaning that it expects that everything coming from database is UTC. Have you found a way to maneuver this I'm currently having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the following line of code:

```php
$todayentry = SensorTissue::whereDate('entryDate', Carbon::now()->setTimezone(config('app.timezone')))
                          ->get()->sortBy('entryDate');
```

with the following code:

```php
$timeZone = config('app.timezone'); //change over here
$todayentry = SensorTissue::whereDate('entryDate', Carbon::now($timeZone))
                          ->get()->sortBy('entryDate');
```

Comment: 2. I change the MySQL global and session timezone to +8.00, it doesn't work too. I think this is from the JSON itself, maybe have the default settings of timezone which required to be modify?